# Retrieve specific keys and values from a nested dictionary and assign them into a new dictionary in python 3.X

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am currently new to python and my objective currently is to retrieve specific keys and values from a JSON data that I have converted into a dictionary format from a RESTful API and assign them to a new dictionary so that I can display them in a HTML template in flask in table form.

Below is the JSON data mentioned and I want to extract only the "dateRented", "username" in "user", "vehicleModel" and "vehicleBrand" in "vehicle".

```
[
  {
    "dateRented": "2020-05-22", 
    "recordsID": 1, 
    "user": {
      "firstname": "Ching", 
      "imageName": "croppedCY", 
      "password": "gAAAAABeuQsw-u6FTh3_2VZiXZGTuiJEhbBuLB4FwyPj5xKb33tkJ7HTH7YvZTWxi0MJ3UKqLQAd6LHoXgCahB1gC5qJo9wSHw==", 
      "surname": "Loo", 
      "userID": 10, 
      "username": "CY"
    }, 
    "vehicle": {
      "colour": "White", 
      "cost": 15, 
      "latitude": null, 
      "longitude": null, 
      "rentalStatus": "True", 
      "seats": 4, 
      "user": null, 
      "vehicleBrand": "Honda", 
      "vehicleID": 4, 
      "vehicleModel": "CRZ"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in the json file have object inside the list you can use loop to iterate through each object in the list then you can easily get the values using `dict.get()` method it will return the value if the given key exist otherwise it will return default value.

```
import json

with open('data.json') as fp:
    data = json.loads(fp.read())

for x in data:
    date_rented = x['dateRented']
    user_name = x['user'].get('username', '')
    vehicle_brand = x['vehicle'].get('vehicleBrand', '')
    vehicle_model = x['vehicle'].get('vehicleModel', '')
    print(date_rented, user_name, vehicle_brand, vehicle_model)
    #2020-05-22 CY Honda CRZ
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say your dictionary is called "my_data"

and you have a new dictionary called "new_dict"

You would do something like this:

```
new_dict["dateRented"] = my_data[0]["dateRented"]
new_dict["username"] = my_data[0]["user"]["username"]
new_dict["vehicleModel"] = my_data[0]["vehicle"]["vehicleModel"
new_dict["vehicleBrand"] = my_data[0]["vehicle"]["vehicleBrand"]
```